# Returning a Struct pointer in a class function

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am getting a set of errors because of my function that tries to return a pointer to a struct. There are a lot of complicating factors in me trying to figure this out, but here is the class:

```
template <typename T>
class AVL : public BST<T>
{
public:
    AVL(void) { head = NULL; }
    ~AVL();
    virtual void insertEntry(T info); 
    virtual void deleteEntry(T info); 
    virtual bool isThere(T info);
protected:
    struct t_node
{
    string data;
    t_node *L;
    t_node *R;
};
t_node* head; 
t_node* cPTR; //current pointer
t_node* pPTR; //parent pointer
int difference(t_node *tPTR);
int height(t_node *tPTR);
t_node* balance(t_node *tPTR);
//these functions can be read as:
//l2l_ROT = left to left rotation
//r2l_ROT = right to left rotation
void l2l_ROT(t_node *pPTR);
void r2r_ROT(t_node *pPTR);
void l2r_ROT(t_node *pPTR);
void r2l_ROT(t_node *pPTR);

};//end of class AVL
```

and here is the function that i am getting errors with:

```
template <typename T>
t_node *AVL<T>::balance(t_node *tPTR)
{
    int factor = difference(tPTR);
    if( factor > 1)
{
    if(difference(tPTR->L) > 0)
        tPTR = ll_rotation(tPTR);
    else
        tPTR = lr_rotation(tPTR);
}

else if(factor < -1)
{
    if(diff(tPTR->right) > 0)
        temp = rl_rotation(tPTR);
    else
        temp = rr_rotation(tPTR);
}
     return tPTR;
   }
```

I apologize for the bad spacing i can never figure out how to correctly copy & paste my code. Also: here is the errors i'm getting:

```
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C2923: 'AVL' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C2065: 'avl_node' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'BST<T>::tPTR'
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C3867: 'BST<T>::tPTR': function call missing argument list; use '&BST<T>::tPTR' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\jordin\desktop\attempts\attempt1\consoleapplication1\avl.h(75): error C2568: '*' : unable to resolve function overload
```

The first error, im confused with how there is a syntax error, there isn't any syntax errors before this i have triple checked.
EDIT:
   In c++ visual studio 2012, the compiler doesn't even highlight the "t_node" in the actual C++ part, as in t_node is black with no link to any data type. Any reasons why this could be?

Comment: StackOverflow works better with spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: what is `avl_node` ? The compiler doesnt know either...

Comment: And what is line 75 of avl.h ?

Comment: yes! That was a mistake i will update it, it's supposed to be t_node :P thank you! Still same error with that fix, unfortunately.

Comment: `t_node *AVL<T>::balance(avl_node *tPTR)` Here, `t_node` is searched in the global namespace. Try `auto AVL<T>::balance(avl_node *tPTR) -> t_node *` instead.

Comment: @dyp Thank you! That worked! Could you possibly explain this a little more? My understanding from what you are saying is that it would need to be declared as a global struct? In the class, for it to find the t_node? Why is this?

Comment: I don't know the rationale, but everything before the *class::* (before or in the *declarator-id*, to be precise) in the definition of a class member outside the class body is looked up in the surrounding scope, and everything afterwards is looked up in the scope of the class first. Therefore, you could either write `typename AVL<T>::t_node * AVL<T>::balance(..)` or `auto AVL<T>::balance(..) -> t_node *` to find the name `t_node` inside `AVL<T>`.

Comment: `typename` is needed (when not using the C++11 syntax) because `t_node` is a dependent name  (the compiler doesn't know whether `AVL<T>::t_node` is a typename or a variable name - you could define a specialization that changes it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the function should be defined the following way

```
template <typename T>
typename AVL<T>::t_node * AVL<T>::balance( typename AVL<T>::t_node *tPTR)
{
    int factor = difference(tPTR);
    if( factor > 1)
{
    if(difference(tPTR->L) > 0)
        tPTR = ll_rotation(tPTR);
    else
        tPTR = lr_rotation(tPTR);
}

else if(factor < -1)
{
    if(diff(tPTR->right) > 0)
        temp = rl_rotation(tPTR);
    else
        temp = rr_rotation(tPTR);
}
     return tPTR;
   }
```

provided that variable `temp` and functions `rr_rotation`, `ll_rotation` and other similar functions are defined in the base class because I do not see their definitions in this derived class.